# Can't find a proper way of storing my data

Tags: java, arrays, storage

I'm making a class attendance system but I need to store names of students during run time. The problem is that if I use a string array it will store the names but how can I store consecutive attendance markings with the names for data of at least 7 days.

Comment: You likely would want to create your own class and have an array of that instead of Strings. I'm struggling to fully understand, though. Could you give more detail?

Comment: It will help us understand your problem more if you include your implementation of storing the data in the `array`, and what you want to do instead of using the `array`.

Comment: You might need to use a `Map` which is an associative array.

Comment: If you created a Student class, and each student had an array of (maybe Booleans?) to keep track of attendance each day. Then you could have an array, or some other collection, of your student objects

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to make this very simple you could use a Map and map the student name to an array of 7 Booleans, with each Boolean representing "present" or "absent" for that day of the week.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you only consider runtime and want an easy management of attendance days once you have more than 7 days. Then as others suggested - you might want to create your own class and store an array of that instead.

If you plan on running longer than 7 days, I'd also consider using List to track attendance in Student class - this way the method that will mark attendance, can simply remove first item from the list if its longer than 7 days and keep the order of days - without you having to do it manually (move every item one spot left) - which would be the case if you store it in array.